# systemd is using >150% CPU

Tags: high-sierra, bug, cpu, temperature, beta-seed-program

I'm not sure what's causing it, but suddenly the `systemd` process just started using about 150% CPU (according to my iStat menu). I checked in Activity Monitor and it said the same. I checked the CPU temperature and it was almost 100℃ so I immediately shut down. I turned it back on and the same thing happened, so I shut down again and, after trying a couple more times, logged into the guest account.

So now I'm in the guest account, everything's fine, but obviously I can't stay here forever. I can get some additional information if you need it, but I don't really want to go back into my user unless it's necessary (100℃ is very high).

Any solutions?

(p.s. I'm running High Sierra 10.13.4 Beta. I'm tempted to get off the Beta version, but I'm not sure how)

Comment: Macs are designed to have could temperature of 100C they will throttle the country if it gets too hot.  However the high Court usage is high